# Looking for a router with multiple WAN ports and load balancing

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dsl, wimax

I'm going to be moving in a few months. The location I'm moving to is great except it's on a road with very few people, so the internet access option is limited to DSL at 1.6Mbps down, 384kbps up. This is much slower than I'm used to. One option is to get at least two of the DSL lines. There's also good possibility that I'll be able to get WiMax or similar.

I've been looking around a bit and it seems like what I need is a load balancing router with multiple WAN ports. Can anyone recommend some good ones?

I could also go with a small power efficient Linux box with multiple NICs. What would be good software for that? It'd need to be able to handle around 10Mbps.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks for the equipment recommendations. Does anyone know if the load balancing on them will be good enough to balance the load from a single windows 7 machine? For instance, web browsing while transferring files via FTP. Would they be smart enough to balance multiple FTP threads?

Comment: I have another option - a T1 for $308 per month, but it's only 1.544Mbps down and up. Seems like I'd be better off with a pair of DSL lines and maybe a WiMax connection.

Answer (score 2):

They may not be available where you are, but I have had good experience with [Drayteks](http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2820.html), which are very popular here in the UK.  They can also be fitted with 3G USB dongles for WAN, in an emergency.

Comment: +1 for the Draytek - The 2820 is great for dual WAN, but needs a Vigor 120 ADSL modem for the second WAN port as it only has one built-in ADSL modem. Very easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Duolinks SW24 2PORT Dual Wan Load Balancing Router](http://www.syswan.com/sw24_overview.htm) in several offices. Works just fine. There was one hickup with DOA but it got replaced very quickly thanks to amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Also in EU I worked with [Fortigate 50B](http://www.fortinet.com/products/fortigate/50B.html) a lot. That one is very decent piece of equipment but expensive.